# If statement not comparing strings properly

Tags: java

I have this code that checks to see if a user input is acceptable. But for some reason it always goes into the if statement. Anyone know why?

```
do{
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of bed " + i + ". (Enter SINGLE, DOUBLE or KING): ");
            bedSize = userInput.next().toUpperCase();
            if (!bedSize.equals("SINGLE") || !bedSize.equals("DOUBLE") || !bedSize.equals("KING")){
                System.out.println("Must enter one of the options; SINGLE, DOUBLE, KING");
            }
        }while(!bedSize.equals("SINGLE") || !bedSize.equals("DOUBLE") || !bedSize.equals("KING"));
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want those to be AND operators `&&` not OR ....

Comment: Why there are down votes, because new user ask wrong question? then who else ask wrong question? Hi @Andrew  - this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
if (!bedSize.equals("SINGLE") && !bedSize.equals("DOUBLE") && !bedSize.equals("KING"))
```

*(If the bed size is different than "SINGLE" **and** different that "DOUBLE" **and** different than "KING")*

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could go

```
List<String> allowed = Arrays.asList("SINGLE", "DOUBLE", "KING");
if(!allowed.contains(bedsize)) {

}
```

Which would be *way better* in terms of later extensions. Say you want to add QUEEN sized beds as well - how much trouble would that cause your `if`s?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, all solved now. I was using OR operators rather than AND. Thanks for the responses!

```
if (!bedSize.equals("SINGLE") && !bedSize.equals("DOUBLE") && !bedSize.equals("KING"))
```

Comment: Yes, that is what some of these users are telling you. Instead of writing your own answer, why not credit one of the individuals who helped you solve your problem?

Comment: that's already been suggested. Check out the other answers and accept one of those please.